# Как вы структурировали товары из выгрузок с admitad?

Tags: php, mysql, api

Есть ли, кто работал с шаблонами экспорта товаров на admitad?
Ситуация такая, я вытаскиваю все товары с id категории и категории товаров из нескольких магазинов с адмитада и храню их у себя в БД.

Категории у каждого магазина свои, с категориями из других магазинов не совпадают.

Необходимо вывести на одной странице товары из всех магазинов, с возможностью фильтрации по категориям. Повторюсь, категории у каждого магазина свои.

Была мысль создать свой список категорий, и привязывать категории из магазинов к своим. Но это долго, т.к. категорий у магазинов может быть около тысячи.
Кто как решал данный момент?

Comment: Как вариант. Можно считать что категории идентичны если у них есть смежный товар, ну к примеру и там и там есть IPhone. Нужно наверно определить процент товаров которые пересекаются и если к примеу 30 % товаров пересекаются тогда считать что это одна и таже категория.  \

Comment: @ВадимБондаренко боюсь мне не подойдет. Если вы имеете в виду, смотреть по названию товара. То в названии может попасться как чехол для Iphone или наушники iphone так и сам телефон iphone. А это разные категории. Не 100%-ный вариант

Comment: Ну у товара должен быть штрих код. Вот если штрих коды одинаковые то это одна категория.

Comment: Нету штрих кодов